# When to use React Error Boundary Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When should we use Error Boundary components? Only for missing props and stuff like that?

For example, imagine this api fetching hook:

```
const useFetch = () => {
   ...
    
   const [error, setError] = useState(null);
 
   const method = async () => {
     try {
        await api.fetchData();
     } catch(err) {
       setError(err);
     }
   };

   useEffect(() => {
     method();
   },[]);

   return { ..., error };
}
```

Now, in a component, I just do:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   const { error } = useFetch();

   if (error) return <FallbackUI />;

   return <MainUI />;
}
```

Can I use an ErrorBoundary component to handle this situation (api call errors) instead of conditionally rendering?

### EDIT

And what about if I only want to display a fallback UI when my fetching data method fails and there any data was previously retrieved?

Something like:

```
const { data, getMoreData, error } = useFetchPosts(); // data is stateful inside the hook
  
if (error && !data) return <FallbackUI />;

return <MainUI data={data} />;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've followed the following approach in my projects that are all hooks/functional component implementations.

I'm using https://github.com/bvaughn/react-error-boundary

```
import { ErrorBoundary } from "react-error-boundary";

<ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}>
   <MyComponent />
</ErrorBoundary>   

//reject the promise so it gets bubbled up
const useFetch = () => {
   ...
    
   const [error, setError] = useState(null);
 
   const method = async () => {
     try {
        await api.fetchData();
     } catch(err) {
       // setError(err);
      return Promise.reject(err);
     }
   };

   useEffect(() => {
     method();
   },[]);

   return { ..., error };
}  


function ErrorFallback({ error }: { error: any }) {
  return (
    <>
      // you custom ui you'd like to return
    </>
  );
}
```

EDIT:

I typically have this at the top level so this is typically a catch all for all the unhandled exceptions. In other words, I wrap my `App.tsx` in the root `index.tsx` file in an `ErrorBoundary`. So, my code looks more like this

```
 ...
 <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}>
    <SWRConfig ...>
       <React.StrictMode>
          <ScrollToTop></ScrollToTop>
             <App ... />
       </React.StrictMode>
      </SWRConfig>
  </ErrorBoundary>
```

Comment: Ohh thx so much! I have thought to do the same for an app restarting UI (wrapping all the tree of components). But... what about typical retriers etc.? I mean, if for example I want to render a retrier component inside some other component that fetch data, should I use a specific error boundary for this? Or conditionally render the fallback or the content of the component?

Comment: I mean, imagine a component that makes 2 fetches (using the same method). If I only want to render a fallback UI when the first fetch fails (ignoring the second one), this should be handled with error boundaries or with conditional renders?

Comment: Something like: const { data, error } = useFetch(someUri);  if(!data && error) return <FallbackUI />;

Comment: hm.., not sure, best I could do is refer you to this article by kent dodds https://kentcdodds.com/blog/use-react-error-boundary-to-handle-errors-in-react